# DropCreateDatabaseAlways with Code First not working with Azure Sql Database

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, azure-service-fabric, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create a Microservices architecture. I have a stateless service combined with Entity Framework deployed on the Azure Service Cluster Fabric.
However my problem is when i have a Initializer with DropCreateDatabaseAlways the database is removed but not recreated.

I have the following Initializer:

```
class CompanyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<CompanyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(CompanyContext context)
    {
        var companies = new List<Company>
        {
            new Company { Name = "AAA", City = "Eindhoven", Streetname="Street 12" },
            new Company { Name = "BBB", City = "Rotterdam", Streetname = "Street 12" },
            new Company { Name = "CCC", City = "Eindhoven", Streetname = "Street 12" }
        };

        companies.ForEach(s => context.Companies.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

With the following context:

```
public class CompanyContext : DbContext
    {
        public CompanyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            Database.SetInitializer<CompanyContext>(new CompanyInitializer());
        }
        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    }
```

And i am connecting these through the constructor of the stateless service:

```
public StatelessServiceCompany(StatelessServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
            _databaseConnectionstring = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Entity.Framework.ConnectionString"];
            _context = new CompanyContext(_databaseConnectionstring);

            new CompanyInitializer().InitializeDatabase(_context);
        }
```

And the connectionstring is as followed:

```
Data Source=*****.*****.****.***;Initial Catalog=******;Integrated Security=False;User ID=********;Password=********;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

The problem is that the database is dropped but never recreated. I believe there are rights missing to create a database through code on the Azure platform.

Secondly Service cluster fabric is not letting me enable migrations for the project. When enabling migrations via the Package manager console i get the following error:

> "System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'StatelessServiceCompany' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was
>   made to load a program with an incorrect format."

How can i solve this. I don't want to make a replicate of Entity Framework via Ado.net.

**Edit**

I solved my problem by deleting the Initializer and enabling migrations. The solution for enabling migration was in the Platform Target under Properties > Build. Switching the platform target between x64 and x86 seems to do the trick. The seed function in the configuration file is also a kind of initializer.

Answer (score 1):

You questions consists of two issues:

- Database initialisation and
- Schema migrations

of which I will only address the first one as that is your primary concern. 
These two issues might be connected as well as might not.

The initializer *DropCreateDatabaseAlways*, unsuprisingly, drops the database when you run the application but it does not recreate a new one immediately. Instead, it waits for the first context usage in particular application domain and only then recreates it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I solved my problem through enabling migrations and deleting the Initializer.

Comment: I have the same problem. The database won't be recreated. I think its an issue of missing rights. Perhaps you only can create a database through the azure portal. This makes first testing and learning experiences in mobile web app development with azure somewhat frustrating and complicated...

Comment: Well, welcome to the ever changing environment of Microsoft Stack.
You surely can create db with the whole schema with Entity Framework directly in Azure, that should not be a problem. I'd suggest asking a separate question.